# Python can add new attribute to function but not to other types

Tags: python, function, methods, attributes

I recently noticed that I can't add my own attributes to built-in types. **BUT** for some reason I can do it with functions. I don't have an idea why does python allow me to add new attribute to a function, but not to even a method... Is the `function` not a built-in type or something?

```
>>> def a():
    """This is an a command. It does nothing"""
    pass

>>> a.help = a.__doc__
>>> a.help
'This is an a command. It does nothing'
>>> class Klass:
    def b():
        """This is a method of Klass class. It does nothing like a."""
        pass

    
>>> obj = Klass()
>>> obj.b.help = obj.b.__doc__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    obj.b.help = obj.b.__doc__
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'help'
>>> setattr(obj.b, "help", obj.b.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    setattr(obj.b, "help", obj.b.__doc__)
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'help'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) where you can get some explanations for that behavior:

> It is not possible to set attributes on bound or unbound methods,
> except by doing so explicitly on the underlying function object.

Set the attributes directly on your method object like in

```
obj.method.__dict__['name'] = value
```

or

```
cls.method.__dict__['name'] = value
```

and it will work.